# Google fonts in Rails app is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use google fonts in my Rails app, but it's not working at all.

application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= render 'layouts/fonts' %>
```

_fonts.html.erb:

```
<!--Google Fonts-->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yesteryear', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

In my SCSS (app.scss) file I have:

```
#feature-text h2 { font-family: 'Yesteryear', cursive; font-size: 46px; color: #000; }
```

Comment: The stylesheet tags you are mentioning should be ideally in application.html.erb as they are applicable to the whole app

Comment: I added the stylesheets tag I have above. Sorry forgot to include that.

Comment: Use your browser to view the source code of your page. Do you see app.<hash>.css included inside <head /> tags?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add http**s** to the google fonts links:

```
<!--Google Fonts-->
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yesteryear', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: I don't think so because your answer doesn't use https either :D

Comment: Haha. Now it does. XD